# Generate PDF from custom fields, and link from Views page

Tags: views, files

I have a list of records that are presented to end-users in a View. That works fine. What I want to do is generate a printable PDF from custom fields so that users can print out a nicely formatted profile page and hand the printout to someone else. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Maybe I should have been more specific that these are custom fields stored within CiviCRM, not as Drupal nodes. Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

I know there is a module called [Views PDF](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_pdf). I did have it working on a test CiviCRM 4.2 site, but formatting the PDF was somewhat tedious and I have never used it on a live site.

Answer (score 1):

We have made use of https://www.drupal.org/project/print multiple times for providing PDF option on a civicrm Views display.